# How improve SELECT about TimeStamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

I made a query which select the `last secods`, for example : if now it's 10:30:30s and I pass the `last 20 seconds` it should return values only between `10:30:10` and `10:30:30`, so here it is:

```
    public List<Log> listLastSeconds(Integer id_point, int seconds) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -seconds);

    Date today = new Date();
    Date lastSeconds = calendar.getTime();

     Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Log l WHERE l.point.id =:id AND l.time >= :lastSeconds AND l.time <= :today", Log.class);
     query.setParameter("id", id_point);
     query.setParameter("lastSeconds", lastSeconds);
     query.setParameter("today", today);

     return query.getResultList();
}
```

But this query is taking too long even for small differences, like 10 seconds.

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_point` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_point_id` (`id_point`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_point_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_point`) REFERENCES `point` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9360244 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2$$
```

How can I improve this query to be more faster ?

Comment: What does your table look like? How is it indexed? Showing the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` would also help.

Comment: Best procedure here it to try and capture the SQL your JPA provider is sending over the wire and then run an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query. Post the results here and your likely to get better answers.

Comment: @Wiseguy I update my post, could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on your `time` colum.  This will do it:

```
CREATE INDEX time_index using btree on log(time);
```

Comment: Michael Slade I update my post, could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DATE_ADD`. First get rid of `today` and `lastSeconds` variables; use this query and set the method arguments as params to the query.

```
SELECT l 
FROM Log l 
WHERE l.point.id =:id
AND l.time >= DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL :seconds SECOND)
```

I would love to test it but dont have mysql access at the moment. Will test it ASAP :)

This, however, may not offer a great performance increase because it will still search the whole table.

if you know something about the nature of the data you are working with, for example what is the wildest number of rows that could possibly be added in the last 10 seconds, then you can add a clause that says table id is greater than max(id) - N, this is just for example, any other indicator that can limit the search space and makes business sense will offer you real performance gains.

an index on the time column is an option, but i am not very familiar with how practical or fast is that? anybody got comments on using an index?